# Safe Algorithm to calculate data hash

Tags: algorithm, security, hash

I would like to send data (4 string values) from my mobile app to backend. To avoid situation where someone whireshark my POST request, and send me some spam, I want to create some data hash, which I will include in POST. Backend will then calculate this hash on his own, and see if posted and calculated hashes match. So the point is that only I would know how this hash is calculated.

My question is, are there any known/recommended solutions or algorithms for this task ?

Comment: A basic rule of cryptography-related security ([Kerckhoff's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle)) means that you must assume your attacker knows all the details of the algorithm — the secrecy is enforced by the keys.  I'm pretty sure that means you need to get into digital signature or similar techniques to the data secure, and/or encrypt the data with a secure algorithm (keeping the appropriate key data secure — with a public key algorithm, of course, the public key is not secret, but the private key must be kept secret).  What you outline is subvertible.

Comment: You just need to use https, it takes care of everything except authenticating the user, which presumably you already do with username and password.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for [HTTP signatures](https://www.securitydrops.com/http-signatures/). They provide authentication and integrity. There is no standard for this yet.

These signature schemes are complex. Opt for HTTPS if you do not need elevated security.

> My question is, are there any known/recommended solutions or algorithms for this task ?

Go with HTTPS. If you really want to “sign” the strings, for [integrity protection](https://www.securitydrops.com/data-integrity/), look into HMAC.